# If $x = \sin(x)$, then is it true that $x = \sin(\sin(\sin(\sin(\cdots(\sin(x))\cdots))))$?

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

> If $x = \sin(x)$, then is the following true?
>   $$x = \sin(\sin(\sin(\sin(\cdots(\sin(x))\cdots))))$$

I don't see a particular reason for not believing it.

Comment: $x=\sin(x) \iff x=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if $a=f(a)$, then $a=f(f(f(\cdots f(a)\cdots)))$. This is easily proved by induction:
$$
f^{n+1}(a)=f(f^n(a))=f(a)=a
$$
This holds for arbitrary sets $A$ and functions $f: A \to A$.